# OpenCV VideoCapture works inconsistently

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, codec

I have been trying to get my application using OpenCV to work for a while now and a longstanding error which I cannot seem to fix is this one:

**PROBLEM:**

OpenCV's VideoCapture is inconsistent in splitting video into frames for different file formats and codecs.

**Specifics:**

My errors are in one part of the application: splitting videos into frames. There are three current scenarios when I choose a valid directory for VideoCapture and open it. It either:

- Opens and works perfectly.
- Is able to open the VideoCapture (cap.isOpened() = true) but receives an empty frame or two during the frame split which causes app to throw error.
- Does not open at all.

A given video will only do one of those three things. AVI File formats seem to have most of the errors, though.

**Fixes tried:**

- Installing K-Lite Codec Pack Full
- Putting OpenCV_FFMPEG.dll and OpenCV_FFMPEG_64.dll in project directory and in PATH

The only explanation I can think of is this is an error with the way I installed OpenCV and FFmpeg.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

By the way, I am running Qt 5.8.0 and OpenCV 3.2.0 and this is my FrameSplit code.

```
vector<int> mainFrame::frameSplit(string filename, string location)
{

//Extract + Save Frames

string vidDir = filename;
string locationDir = location + "/frames/";
VideoCapture cap(vidDir);

if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    qDebug() << "OO";
    return {};
}
else
{
    Mat firstFrame;
    Mat nextFrame;
    Mat frame;
    int count = 1;

    QProgressDialog progress("Extracting files...", "Abort", 0, cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
    progress.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    progress.setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
    progress.setFixedSize(500, 100);
    progress.show();

    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
    compression_params.push_back(100);
    qDebug() << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    bool failure = false;

    for (count = 1; count < cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); count++)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) {
            QMessageBox messageBox;
            messageBox.critical(this, "Error", "There was an error in analyzing the video. Please try and install the appropriate codecs and try again.");
            messageBox.setFixedSize(600,400);
            vector<int> empty;
            return empty;
        }

        string filePath = locationDir + to_string(count) + ".jpg";
        imwrite(filePath,frame,compression_params);
        progress.setValue(count);
    }

    progress.setValue(count);
    progress.close();
    vector<int> props;
    props.push_back(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
    props.push_back(round(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)));
    props.push_back(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
    props.push_back(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    qDebug() << props[0];

    return props;
}
```

}

Comment: As you point out in your question, the problem is opencv, not Qt, so do not use that tag unnecessarily.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sure, I just wanted to keep the option in case it had to do with linking/compatability with Qt.

Comment: First solve one problem at a time, your problem is that it does not read the frames, you have to work it and then attack the following problem.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether the various errors are always associated consistently with the same input files? I mean, does `file1.avi` always work, and `file2.avi` always give empty frames? Or does `file1.avi` sometimes give an error and sometimes give no error or a different error?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Edited the question. `file1.avi` will only ever do one of the three things listed i.e. have a blank frame.

Comment: A given video will always give the same error every time?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Precisely.

Comment: have you tried with another backend? like gstreamer?

Comment: @api55 I will try and get back to you on that

Comment: @api55 I think it is specifically OpenCV's FFmpeg that is causing the issue. FFmpeg's developer libs work just fine, but that adds about 50 more MB to my application. Is there anyway to use OpenCV's FFmpeg?